# Crystal Report Selection Formula date range query

Tags: crystal-reports, report, selection, formula

Pls Help.

I have `{tbInvoice.trx_date} and {tbInvoice.payment_date},` and i have `{?startdate} and {?enddate}` parameter in my CR

Case :

Default value for payment_date is NULL when the trx_date is created, Payment_date will be updated as the customer paid.

Question :

I have to filter only record on April.
How do i filter {tbInvoice.payment_date} is NULL in April and also {tbInvoice.payment_date} is NOT NULL but not in April (in May for example).

Thanks in advance....

Edit------------------------------------------------------------------

```
        if({tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?
    enddateSub} and isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date})) 
then true 
else if({tbInvoice.payment_date}>={?enddateSub} and 
    not(isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date})) and {tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?enddateSub}) 
then true 
else false;
```

Comment: How do you define a `NULL` in any month? how exactly your records are stored in database? can show a sample?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Siva, my english is not good but i hope you understand. In my tbInvoice, i have trx_date to store transaction date, and i didn't INSERT INTO for payment_date --> this makes my payment_date field is NULL. And then when the customer pay, i will update my payement_date field in tbInvoice to store the date of the payment. thanks

Comment: My goal is to filter which invoice (trx_date = on April) that has not paid on April (payment_date = NULL), and maybe paid on May (payment_date = on May, but trx_date on April). Thanks

Comment: See that is my question here when your payment date is null how will you make sure that the payment date is null for month of april.. it can be for month of may aswell.... that is the reason I have asked for sample data. if payment date is the only date field you have in database then it is really hard to tell for which month you have the null.. on the other hand if you have any reference date to this payment date to tell which month that record is falling

Comment: Btw thanks Siva for your time, i just figured out the answer by my self after long day try and error...lol...anyway, i have invoice date field (trx_date) and payment date field (payment_date), both are in tbInvoice. When i save the Invoice, i only INSERT INTO only for invoice date(trx_date), so the payment_date is NULL right? btw, maybe you can see my selection formula below and you can understand what i mean...this formula gives the result i want....hehehe...thanks again for your time

Comment: if({tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?enddateSub} 
    and isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date})) then 
    true 
    else

if({tbInvoice.payment_date}>={?enddateSub} 
    and not(isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date})) and {tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?enddateSub}) then 
    true 
    else false;

Comment: Maybe the right term for this subject is : MULTIPLE IF in selection formula

Comment: Yes that's what my point is... you need have one more date to tell that payment date is null... anyway great you have solved the issue.

Comment: @Siva sorry i need help to apply those selection formula to SQL server query...pls help

Comment: Where did you use these formulas in crystal reports?

Comment: Record selection formula

Comment: try answer and let me know.....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if({tbInvoice.payment_date}>={?enddateSub} and 
    not(isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date})) 
then
{tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?enddateSub} 
else if isnull({tbInvoice.payment_date}) 
then 
{tbInvoice.trxDate}>={?startdateSub} and {tbInvoice.trxDate}<={?
    enddateSub}
```